# Font size multiplier via AccessibilityManager

Tags: react-native, accessibility

I need the value of the font size multiplier, which is set by the accessibility settings of the system (iOS).

Currently I achieve this by calling a method of **AccessibilityManager.m** via:

```
const AccessibilityManager = NativeModules.AccessibilityManager;
console.log(AccessibilityManager.getMultiplier((value) => {
    console.log(value)
}));
```

Is this a **solid** way or could someone suggest me a better approach? It should be usable as a part of a **shared component**.

Comment: That seems straight forward and clever enough. Why do you think you need a 'better ' way? Btw, *applause* for baking accessibility into your app!

Comment: I thought about a more "official api", instead of calling the accessibilitymanager directly. Something like the PixelRatio component / api. Because I don't see any reasons against my solution, I was just interested in other opinions. Just in the moment, I shipped a new  of the relevant component. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you're doing exactly the right thing. Have you open-sourced the component itself?

Comment: Yes I did. The approach is used by the `Cell`-Component of [react-native-tableview-simple](https://github.com/Purii/react-native-tableview-simple)

Comment: Note that multiplier can change while the app is running, however this event is not posted by `AccessibilityManager` so you'd have to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions) for that:

```
console.log(Dimensions.get("window").fontScale)


// Or use the listener to get an updated value
Dimensions.addEventListener("change", ({ window }) => {
  console.log(window.fontScale);
});
```

Comment: There is now a preferred way based on hooks: https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions